# using ui-router and databinding seems to be broken

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using a controller in my application... when the view loads its hits the breakpoints in the controller and by all accounts it seems to work.

```
angular.module('main.controllers', ['ui.router','ngAutocomplete','nouislider','ui.bootstrap']).
    controller('CandidateDashboardCtrl', function($scope,$state,$modal,$log) {
        $scope.awesomethings = 'HTML5 Boilerplate';

    });
```

In my view I have an input

```
<input type="text" ng-model="awesomethings" />
```

This shows HTML5 Boilerplate in my input value

However if I reference {{awesomethings}} it does not work at all.

Does anyone know why?   The only thing different is I am using ui-router as opposed to ngRoute and states rather than direct url references.  Everything else seems to work fine.

Comment: Where are you trying to put {{awesomethings}} that it doesn't work? If you added `<span>{{awesomethings}}</span>` below your `input`, it should update as you update the `input`.

Comment: I figured it out... had to make a custom interpolator {[{ }]} because the normal braces were interfering with hogan templates